# Android Orientation problem while recording the screen

Tags: screen, orientation

I have i weird problem with my android RK3288 motherboard.

I set the orientation of the screen to reverse portrait but if i want to record the screen or do remote control via scrcpy i got a screen like it's still under landscape mode.

After i tried to change the system properties like this but no result :

```
adb shell settings put system accelerometer_rotation 0  #disable auto-rotate
adb shell settings put system user_rotation 2  #reverse portrait
```

I tried also to rotate the hdmi screen in /system/build.prop but also no result :

```
persist.demo.hdmirotation=portrait
persist.demo.hdmirotationlock=true
persist.demo.singledisplay=true
```

**Remote or screen record display :**

[image: Remote or screen record display :]

**HDMI screen display :**

[image: HDMI screen display :]